# Non-increasing Function of Measurable Sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

I'm stuck trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $f$ be a non-negative measurable function on a finite measure space $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ and let $\lambda(t)=\mu(\{x\in X~:~f(x)>t\})$. Prove that $\lambda$ is a non-increasing function of $t$ and is continuous from the right; i.e. $\lim_{h\searrow 0}\lambda(t+h)=\lambda(t)$.

So, to show that $\lambda$ is non-increasing, I believe we need to show that $\lambda(t_{1})\geq\lambda(t_{2})$ whenever $t_{1}<t_{2}$. I'm assuming that I need to use the fact that $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ is a *finite* measure space to show that $\lambda$ is a non-increasing function in $t$. Other than this, I have no ideas on how to tackle this problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If $t>s$, then $\{f > t\} \subseteq \{f > s\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t_1< t_2,$ then $f(x)>t_2 $ implies that $t(x)>t_1,$ so you have $$ \{x\in X :f(x)>t_2\}\subseteq \{x\in X :f(x)>t_1\},$$ so since the measure of a measurable set is always greater than or equal to the measure of a measurable subset, we have $ \lambda(t_2)\le \lambda(t_1).$

For the continuity part, use the theorem about [continuity of measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Continuity_from_above).

Comment: Okay, I was thinking that there was some subset containment that I would need to work with. I don't know why I didn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints:

Suppose $t_1<t_2$.  What can you say about the sets $\{x\in X:f(x)>t_1\}$ and $\{x\in X:f(x)>t_2\}$?  Is one a subset of the other?

To show continuity from the right, it suffices to show that if $(h_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}h_n=0$, then $\lim\lambda(t+h_n)=\lambda(t)$.  Can you deduce anything about the sets $\{x\in X:f(x)>t+h_n\}$, $\{x\in X:f(x)>t\}$?  Once you have that, use some sort of continuity of measures to deduce the right-continuity of $\lambda$ (this is where finiteness of $\mu$ comes into the picture).